# How to get calendar events from Exchange 2016

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

We are currently running Exchange 2016 in our environment NOT office365.  I am not  a windows  developer or know much about Microsoft  products (nothing wrong them them, I just dont have experience with them.)  I am building a display that will show me my current calendar events.  I am using python and a raspberry pi to do this.  I have found the article on google below, but it appears to be only avail for office 365 which we dont use.  Is there a way to get the calendar events some other way, or use the Graph API on our exchange server instead of office 365?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options either:

- do the hybrid setup and use the Microsoft Graph API to [list events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
- Use one of these [library](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/), [library](https://pypi.org/project/py-ews/) to connect to the Exchange web service, aka **EWS**.